# Check if a function returns false in Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement

In python, I am currently doing this:

```
if user_can_read(request.user, b) == False:
```

Is there any other way of checking if the function returns `False`?

Comment: `if not function_return_boolean():`

Comment: `if user_can_read(request.user,b) is False:`

Comment: The BDFL suggests explicitly checking if the return value is an instance of `bool` and nhahtdh's method if you specifically want to compare with `False` and not just any falsy value, since `is False` is nearly always a bug.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could just use

```
if user_can_read(request.user, b):
    ## do stuff
```

If `user_can_read` returns *anything* (except 0, False, etc), it will be considered True, and do stuff.

And the negation: `if not user_can_read(request.user, b)`

Comment: @iyrag: As a side note, a common mistake is to assume that negative numbers evaluate to `False`. This is wrong, `bool(-1)` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Joel: People really believe that negative numbers evaluate to `False`?  That surprises me.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I've come across this a few times. It probably stems from the fact that traditionally, a search with no result should return `-1` (since `0` is taken up by the first index).